# issue converting SQL query into RPC function

Tags: sql, supabase, supabase-database

I am having trouble converting a query into an RPC function...I am 7yrs experienced on Front End, with 4 months BE spinkled in for the project I am working on.  I am working with ChatGPT to try and create an RPC method I can call from my Node/Express server, but it has not been able to figure it out.

This query works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pattern, MAX(created_at) AS latest_created_at
FROM public.submitted_images
WHERE user_id = user_id AND pattern IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY pattern
ORDER BY latest_created_at DESC, pattern
LIMIT 10;
```

however, when converting it to a function that gets called, it returns null .  What is it about this method that fails?  No errors are visible.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_top_10_patterns_by_user(user_id uuid)
RETURNS TABLE (pattern text, latest_created_at timestamp) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT DISTINCT pattern, MAX(created_at) AS latest_created_at
    FROM public.submitted_images
    WHERE user_id = get_top_10_patterns_by_user.user_id AND pattern IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY pattern
    ORDER BY latest_created_at DESC, pattern
    LIMIT 10;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks for helping clarify

Comment: remove `distinct` in your query it is 100% redundant as the `group by` will form unique rows

Comment: your function includes this `user_id = get_top_10_patterns_by_user.user_id`  you can't compare a single value on one side and 10 rows on the other side of an equals operator,

Comment: thanks...neither of those suggestions worked...still null

Comment: "distinct" **is redundant** - you simply do not need it when using `group by` - but removing it will not fix the other issue of returning NULL

Comment: the goal of the query was to return a unique list of `pattern` rows, based on the provided `user_id`, ordered by `created_at` in descending order, and then return the first 10

Answer (score 0):

Below I have revised the function code so that it returns data (in a postges fiddle). Please note that for simplicity I used an integer type for the user_id you will need to revise that to uuid.

```
CREATE TABLE submitted_images (
    id INT,
    user_id INT,
    pattern text,
    created_at TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO submitted_images (id, user_id, pattern, created_at) 
VALUES
    (4, 1, 'pattern3', '2023-01-04 12:00:00'),
    (5, 2, 'pattern1', '2023-01-05 12:00:00'),
    (6, 3, 'pattern2', '2023-01-06 12:00:00'),
    (7, 1, 'pattern3', '2023-01-07 12:00:00'),
    (8, 2, 'pattern2', '2023-01-08 12:00:00'),
    (9, 3, 'pattern1', '2023-01-09 12:00:00'),
    (10, 1, 'pattern2', '2023-01-10 12:00:00'),
    (11, 2, 'pattern3', '2023-01-11 12:00:00'),
    (12, 3, 'pattern1', '2023-01-12 12:00:00'),
    (13, 1, 'pattern3', '2023-01-13 12:00:00');

-- does NOT contain "distinct"
SELECT pattern, MAX(created_at) AS latest_created_at
FROM public.submitted_images
WHERE user_id = user_id AND pattern IS NOT NULL
  -- group by forms rows that are unique
GROUP BY pattern
ORDER BY latest_created_at DESC, pattern
LIMIT 10;
```

| pattern | latest_created_at |
| --- | --- |
| pattern3 | 2023-01-13 12:00:00 |
| pattern1 | 2023-01-12 12:00:00 |
| pattern2 | 2023-01-10 12:00:00 |

```
-- including "distinct" is redundant, it achieves nothing here
SELECT DISTINCT pattern, MAX(created_at) AS latest_created_at
FROM public.submitted_images
WHERE user_id = user_id AND pattern IS NOT NULL
  -- group by forms rows that are unique
GROUP BY pattern
ORDER BY latest_created_at DESC, pattern
LIMIT 10;
```

| pattern | latest_created_at |
| --- | --- |
| pattern3 | 2023-01-13 12:00:00 |
| pattern1 | 2023-01-12 12:00:00 |
| pattern2 | 2023-01-10 12:00:00 |

**revised function**

Note I would not name the parameter just "user_id", i.e. make sure you can easily identify the parameter. You also need to identify the table with all column references, here I have aliased the table as "si". Note you should not include "select distinct" when using `group by`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_top_10_patterns_by_user(user_id_param integer)
RETURNS TABLE (pattern text, latest_created_at timestamp) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT si.pattern, MAX(si.created_at) AS latest_created_at
    FROM submitted_images AS si
    WHERE si.user_id = get_top_10_patterns_by_user.user_id_param AND si.pattern IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY si.pattern
    ORDER BY latest_created_at DESC, si.pattern
    LIMIT 10;
END;
$$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call the function:

```
SELECT * FROM get_top_10_patterns_by_user(1);
```

| pattern | latest_created_at |
| --- | --- |
| pattern3 | 2023-01-13 12:00:00 |
| pattern2 | 2023-01-10 12:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2NQV-DfN)